# How to reload or refresh entire branch(parent+children) in kendo treeview

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, treeview

I have this [DEMO](https://dojo.telerik.com/isOqOXEr) where onExpand function will reload its children.

**In this example:** If I checked the children then collapse-expand it will refresh.

**Problem:** If i check the parent node all children will be checked and if I collapse-expand the parent node and also the children are not **reloading**.

Comment: The scenario is not quite clear - which node is expanded and which checked - would you please share the exact step that should be performed and what you expect to happen?

Comment: @PlamenZdravkov Hi! So if I check a children node, and collapse-expand it will refresh the whole branch. If I check a parent node, ofcourse the children will be checked all, then when I collapse-expand, the branch didnt refresh. It should be refreshed also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The load method is only reloading the child items - if you want to reset the checked state of the parent itself you will have to address the checked state. Here is a [dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/isOqOXEr/4) that worked at my side.